# How to redirect old page link to new link when using new CMS for website

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, cms, 302-redirect

We are doing a new website and the current  website `www.domains.com` has been running for almost 3 years and is quite visible on search engines.

Now we are working on new website with multilingual features and we are also using custom cms that is developed using asp.net webform.

and we have new url for which will render old url useless.

for example in current website internship page can be accessed via two url 
`Internship`
http://www.domain.com/internship/
http://www.domain.com/internship/Default.aspx

and `Employment` page can also be accessed via two url

http://www.domain.com/employment/
http://www.domain.com/employment/Default.aspx

Now with new cms following for the above mentioned `internship` page we use following url

http://www.domain.com/en/internship/1/21/internship

since new website actually doen't contain folder `internship` i was thinking of  creating a folder `internship` and default.aspx and make it 301 redirect  from `http://www.domain.com/internship/Default.aspx` to `http://www.domain.com/en/internship/1/21/internship`

is this approach correct.

I looked for best approach on net and found this article which has also confused me http://moz.com/blog/save-your-website-with-redirects as it now showing any practical example. as other article save we should use 302 redirect etc...

Please advise how can i make a redirect from the old website link which is `http://www.domain.com/internship/Default.aspx` TO new website link `http://www.domain.com/en/internship/1/21/internship` which basically has same contents.

appreciate reply on this

Comment: FYI, you don't actually have to make a folder to have it redirect to another folder.

Comment: Agree with you i can use HTTP handlers in asp.net to track & redirect with 3013 redirect. I think this is what you meant also..

Comment: Yes, you need 301 redirects, not 302.